# Nuget how to add files to solution folder

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have a package that contains some files that I want added at a solution level rather than a project level.  I am able to add a folder at the solution level, but cannot determine how to add my files into to this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by placing your code in the init.ps1 file. install.ps1 only executes with project-level packages. Because the code will be in init.ps1, it will run every time the solution loads - not just at install. so you will need to safeguard against re-execution. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460854/adding-solution-level-items-in-a-nuget-package) for a code example - You'll just need to add a step to copy from the tools folder to the solution folder.