# Remove solution folders using NuGet uninstall.ps

Tags: powershell, nuget

In my NuGet package, I add a solution folder using the method shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478804/1628707

Here's my code to add the solution folder, in Init.ps.

```
$solutionFolder = $solution.AddSolutionFolder("build")
$folderItems = Get-Interface $solutionFolder.ProjectItems ([EnvDTE.ProjectItems])
$files = Get-ChildItem "$buildFolder"
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $folderItems.AddFromFile($file.FullName)
}
```

Now, in Uninstall.ps, I want to remove the solution folder named "build." I've tried the following.

```
//try to get the solution folder. This fails with 'doesn't contain a method named Item'
$proj = $solution.Projects.Item("build")

//So, I tried enumerating and finding the item by name. This works.
foreach ($proj in $solution.Projects)
{
  if ($proj.Name -eq "build")
  {
    $buildFolder = $proj
  }
}

//But then removing fails with 'doesn't contain a method named Remove'
$solution.Remove($buildFolder)
```

I'm stymied and will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I was having issues with a similar problem but have managed to crack it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769227/remove-project-from-solution-via-package-manager-console/28483691#28483691)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Item is being difficult but another way to do this would be:

```
$proj = $solution.Projects | Where {$_.ProjectName -eq "build"}
```