# Solution items, Nuget and deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I have a nuget package with ~30mb of content items. It is used in several projects of solution versioned with svn. Content items are included automatically in every project and become versioned several times. Also content items are changed frequently, so every commit with update of nuget takes up + 60-90 mb of space (old content deleted, new appeared. so no patches).

I moved these contents files to solution folder (like in question "[Adding solution-level items in a NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460854/adding-solution-level-items-in-a-nuget-package)") to prevent data duplication and added svn ignore on these files.

Is there any good way to automatically deploy script which is copying solution files after build to output directory to projects where nuget package is installed?

Comment: I can understand this pain. I had a same problem. But i took a different approach. Since i work in a large enterprise environment. We created a nuget server resolved the problem. But for you i guess powershell is the best option for this

Comment: How does a nuget server help includiong solutions files in build? or you simply ignore all contents in svn and use package restore upon build in CI server?

Comment: Yep that's right we do the package restore but those packages are kept in server as per developers requirement. Suppose you need newton.DLL you will be able to keep that in server and refer that server as your nuget server. But as far as I get what you are trying to achieve the option I could think for you is either using powershell, or WIX(Windows Installer XML) or use custom ms build extensions. There is a msbuild extension community with lots of things that meet your need.