# Native binaries in NuGet package installed into DNX project

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, dnx

I've created NuGet package containing native x86 binaries. Binaries are copying to bin directory by MSBuild script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511034/1801039).

But this approach does not work with DNX projects (ASP.NET 5 web app for example), because MSBuild script is not installing. So I have FileNotFoundException.

How to make it alive?

Comment: You could include your native bits by updating the project.json file - e.g. https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/project.json#L84-L90
You can also take a look at the post I wrote on using native libraries in ASP.NET 5: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/10/using-native-libraries-in-asp-net-5/ but I don't know if it will be useful for you if you don't distribute your native binaries as NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was to make runtimes\win\native directory in NuGet package structure, as described here: https://docs.nuget.org/Create/uwp-create

In runtime DNX adds this directory to PATH variable, so managed dll can load it.