# How to add C++ library in a .NET Core project

Tags: c++, dll, .net-core

How is the way to add a C++ Library in a .NET Core project (Class Library). I tried creating a nuget package but doesn't work. I got this error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in "NameOfDll.dll"`

When I add the nuget package the project.json add the following reference:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "NameOfDll.dll": "1.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*dependencies* attribute in `project.json` specifies package dependencies, because of this NuGet handles `NameOfDll.dll` as a package ID, but not as a dll name.

To add native C++ dlls into you NuGet package for `.xproj` library you should do the following steps:

1. Put your `NameOfDll.dll` in `\lib` directory near `MyClassLibrary.xproj`
2. Open `project.json` file and add there:

   ```
   "packOptions": {
     "files" : {
       "includeFiles" : "lib/NameOfDll.dll"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Execute `dotnet pack`

`NameOfDll.dll` will be included into NuGet package under the path `lib\NameOfDll.dll`.

To add native C++ dlls into your NuGet package for `.csproj` library you should do the following steps:

1. I assume you have managed project with name `MyClassLibrary.csproj`.
2. Create new NuGet package for you class library with `nuget spec` command.
3. Create `\lib`, `\build`, `\content` and `\tools` directories near `MyClassLibrary.nuspec`.
4. Copy all your native dlls into the `\build` folder.
5. Change extension of copied native dlls to `.native`.
6. Create `MyClassLibrary.targets` with the following content inside `\build` folder:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <ItemGroup>
       <AvailableItemName Include="NativeBinary" />
     </ItemGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
       <NativeBinary Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*">
         <TargetPath></TargetPath>
       </NativeBinary>
     </ItemGroup>
     <PropertyGroup>
       <PrepareForRunDependsOn>
         $(PrepareForRunDependsOn);
         CopyNativeBinaries
       </PrepareForRunDependsOn>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <Target Name="CopyNativeBinaries" DependsOnTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
       <Copy SourceFiles="@(NativeBinary)"
             DestinationFiles="@(NativeBinary->'$(OutDir)\%(TargetPath)\%(Filename).dll')"
             Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.native'">
         <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites" />
       </Copy>
       <Copy SourceFiles="@(NativeBinary)"
             DestinationFiles="@(NativeBinary->'$(OutDir)\%(TargetPath)\%(Filename).%(Extension)')"
             Condition="'%(Extension)'!='.native'">
         <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites" />
       </Copy>
     </Target>
   </Project>
   ```

   *Hint*: The `.targets` content is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478775/add-native-files-from-nuget-package-to-project-output-directory) question.
   The above `.targets` file will be injected on an installation of the NuGet package into the target project file.
7. Add the following lines into your `MyClassLibrary.nuspec`:

   ```
   <files>
     <file src="lib\" target="lib" />
     <file src="tools\" target="tools" />
     <file src="content\" target="content" />
     <file src="build\" target="build" />
   </files>
   ```
8. Execute `nuget pack MyClassLibrary.csproj` to build your NuGet package.

Comment: Hi @gemr1423! Does it solve your problem or you need more help?

Comment: Hi @Nikita I have a question, is the same with .xproj?

Comment: @gemr1423 Info about packing of native dlls with `xproj` added.

Comment: Hi @Nikita, I got the same error trying to execute a method of the C++ DLL in the class library project. I was done the steps that you explain without error. "Unable to load DLL 'TLHDArchive.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" I calling the method this way: [DllImport("NameOfDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

Comment: @gemr1423 I've found an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4021) at their bug tracking system about it. `dotnet` doesn't copy included files of installed packages. According to the  [release roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) next 1.1 version will be available soon and you will be able to use the second proposed solution. .NET Core will migrate from `project.json` to `.csproj` and `MSBuild`.

Comment: @gemr1423 Refer to the [Dotnet/corefxlab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) project as a sample of right `"packOptions"` usage. Component [`System.Drawing.Graphics`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/71d1b2220a59d1780aafc04d42a58e15296fc96f/src/System.Drawing.Graphics/project.json#L19) uses the same approach to include `libgd.dll` native library.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nikita

Comment: I got "The method or operation is not implemented." when trying .csproj on macOS 10.12     
`$ nuget pack MyClassLibrary.csproj
 Attempting to build package from MyClassLibrary.csproj.
 System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.`

Comment: my nuget package maker on macOS was **2.12.0.0** and after upgrading it to  **4.1.0.2450** fixed the above error _(However i am not getting a different error)_

Comment: if `nuget pack MyClassLibrary.csproj` doesn't work then we can try `dotnet pack MyClassLibrary.csproj`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-click way to do it in .net core 2. I used it in my website and it works.

Right click your project in Solution Explorer, select Add->Existing Item, browse and choose your dll (select show all extensions). Then your dll will appear in Solution explorer.

In the Solution Explorer, right-click your dll -> Properties. Set build action: Content, and Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer (or always copy).

It's done. Use your dll in your code staightforward like this:

```
[DllImport("my_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```