# ProjectReference to native project from sdk-style project

Tags: .net, .net-core

I had a framework project that had a reference to a vcxproj project. I converted this project to a .netstandard2.0 project, using sdk-style projects. Now, I get an error about missing project info.

How can my standard project reference a c++ project such that they both get compiled in dependency order. Is this supported?

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.513\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error NETSDK1007: Cannot find project info for 'd:\depot\master4\private\mt\common\UnicodeNormalizer\UnicodeNormalizer.vcxproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  <Configurations>Debug;Release;</Configurations>
  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
  <ProjectGuid>{f7af5355-9510-42df-baf6-01748e9dc625}</ProjectGuid>
  <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  <NoWarn>0618</NoWarn>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup> 
  <ProjectReference Include="$(EnlistmentRoot)\private\mt\common\UnicodeNormalizer\UnicodeNormalizer.vcxproj"/>
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Does your c++ project targets .NET Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add C++ library in a .NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377602/how-to-add-c-library-in-a-net-core-project)

Comment: No it's just a c++ project. The other question is adding a c++ library to link to at runtime. I want to add a c++ project so that it gets built as a dependency of my standard project

Comment: @Fai Did you have any luck with this yet?

Comment: @Chiel I posted an answer of what I ended up using

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around that looks like this. This does build the project and places the produced dll in the output of this project. Note this won't build on linux. dotnet can't parse the vcxproj file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(EnlistmentRoot)\private\mt\common\UnicodeNormalizer\UnicodeNormalizer.vcxproj">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Targets>Build;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup</Targets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(EnlistmentRoot)\private\mt\common\UnicodeNormalizer\$(ProjectOutputPath)\UnicodeNormalizer.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```