# How to create a nuget package supporting multiple platforms

Tags: .net, nuget, packaging, multiplatform, nuspec

First of all I read a few articles in this regards like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks but they don't cover my scenario and whatever I tried didn't work.

I have totally 4 assemblies with the following configuraitons:

```
1. .NET Framework 4.5; Platform x86
2. .NET Framework 4.5; Platform x64
3. UWP10; Platform x86
4. UWP10; Platrofm x64
```

I don't have AnyCPU platform assemblies even for .NET Framework. All my assemblies either target x86 or x64. Everything that I found so far describes how to create a multi-platform package for UWP only. I didn't even try that yet because that topic is well covered. The question is how to package multi-platform package for .NET Framework 4.5. In accordance with the packaging articles it seems I have to have the following folder structure

```
runtimes
   win-x86
      lib
         net45
            MyAssembly.dll
   win-x64
      lib
         net45
            MyAssembly.dll
```

I created this structure and tried to consume the package. The package installs without errors but I cannot use MyAssembly.dll. It looks like the build does not find it. I tried different variations of folder names like "win10-x86", just "x86". Nothing works.

Is it even possible to have multi-platform packages for .NET Framework 4.5? Is there anybody who successfully created one? Please share the knowledge.

Thank you

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478775/add-native-files-from-nuget-package-to-project-output-directory? Check the most voted answer.

Comment: I saw that question. The question is more than 4 years old and if I'm not mistaken back than there was no "runtimes" section in NuGet whatsoever and in that situation I understand the solution was introduced via custom targets. Since then NuGet improved a lot and I assumed it's possible now to build platform specific packages for .NET Framework. I'm probably missing something to make it work.

Comment: I also wonder how this is possible, especially with SDK style projects.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since you asked the question; did you have any luck or find a workaround?

If you check the documentation you [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#architecture-specific-folders), it (now) says

> These assemblies will only be available at runtime, so if you want to provide the corresponding compile time assembly as well then have `AnyCPU` assembly in `/ref/{tfm}` folder.

Thus, in addition to the runtimes folder, it seems you need an `AnyCPU` version of your library to support building, which is where it seems you were having problems.