# Output Directory of native dll bundled with NuGet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to build a NuGet package that includes native DLLs which are to be placed in the output folder when a project uses the package. I have tried to use the several suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19478775/347964), but I am always running in the same problem.

My current NuGet package layout is like this:

```
\build
  packageId.targets
  file1.dll
  file2.dll
\lib
  \netstandard1.4
    assembly.dll
```

The contents of `packageId.targets` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\*.dll"/>
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)" Link="$(RecursiveDir)$(Filename)$(Extension)">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This should, according to the answers of the other questions, lead to my DLLs being placed in the `bin\Debug` directory of the project using the package. However, they are not. Instead, they are placed in `bin\Debug\packages\packageId\build`.

Now I have experimented a lot, and I noticed more and more strange behavior which I cannot make any sense of:

- If I move the DLLs to the root of the NuGet package (like one answer suggests) and change the `.targets` file accordingly, *they are not copied at all*. There also is no error message.
- If I change the `.targets` file to *only* reference `file1.dll` in both `Include=` and `Link=`, both files get copied anyway.
- So I wondered if some policy just ignores the `.targets` file and copies whatever is in `build` to that path in the output folder, but when I remove the `.targets` file, the DLL files will not get copied anymore.

Now I understand even less what's happening.

What do I need to change to get the DLLs copied right into `bin\Debug`?

Comment: This seems to have been a Visual Studio bug. Updating to the latest version made the DLLs being placed directly in the ouptut directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new way to handle runtime-specific assents in NuGet is to use the `runtimes` folder to place native assets:

```
\lib
  \netstandard2.0
    ManagedWrapper.dll
\runtimes
  \win-x86
    \native 
     NativeThing.dll
  \win-x64
    \native 
     NativeThing.dll
  \linux-x64
    \native 
     libNativeThing.so
  \osx-x64
    \native 
     libNativeThing.dylib
```

If the package is consumed from a .NET Framework project, you may need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` package wich provides the runtime graph (`runtimes.json`) for NuGet to provide proper RID mappings if you don't use base RIDs (e.g. `win10-x64` falls back to `win-x64` resources).

Comment: Thanks for this. But won't I lose the compatibility I get by using .NET Standard when I reference something in .NET Core? That is to say: When I use this feature, will I potentially sacrifice compatibility? Because if I do, then it seems to be wiser to stick to my solution that works since the latest VS update.

Comment: Not sure wha you loose. If you reference this netstandard library from a .NET Core application, it should either put the runtimes folder into the output directory (portable app) or the right native asset into the main output folder (RID-specific output / self-contained)

Comment: Or do you mean that the package containing the graph has `NETCore` in it? that's just unfortunate naming. the package doesn't have much to do with .NET Core.

Comment: Ah okay. Then all is well, thanks for the clarification.