# Visual Studio is creating ref folder

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, ref

I have noticed that VS2019 creates this 'ref' folder inside my project. It contains just bunch of DLL's and I get an error when I try to delete it. When I close VS and delete bin and obj folders and reopen solution it is not there but gets created again shortly after.

I could not find much info on what is the purpose of this folder and why it appears there. Any information is appreciated. I also add screen shot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Oh, maybe I forgot to mention that I use .NET Core 3.1 and all my packages are on their latest version available. Also I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsService maybe this is the cause?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There's not enough information here for me to go on. I certainly don't get it when I create a new .NET Core 3.1 web app or console app.

Comment: Besides, I think this issue is more related to some specific nuget packages folder. And the icon on the `ref` folder are the files introduced by the nuget package. So, you can try to create a new project, install the existing nuget packages one by one, and see which one it is. Or share all your nuget package information directly with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It contains just bunch of DLL's and I get an error when I try to
>   delete it. When I close VS and delete bin and obj folders and reopen
>   solution it is not there but gets created again shortly after.

**I think this issue is caused by some specific nuget packages if there are no other scripts for your project .**  And there is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838867/nuget-package-silently-adds-back-deleted-files-to-project-directory-not-only-ini).

And the nuget package contains some `<package_id>.targets` or `props` files or `contentfiles` tag to import some extra files into your project and it created the `ref` folder which included some useful files in your situation due to it.

**Let me explain it in more detail**：

When you create a nuget package and want to import some extra files or do some extra operation when you install this package into a new main project, you can use [MSBuild props and targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package), [contentfiles tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files) or [powershell scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory) to import some extra files into the new project.

**Usually**, the author creates them for a specific purpose, so please do not delete them easily in projects which will cause other problems. Besides, the author will add some sort of recovery mechanism to prevent accidental deletion of the file from being unrecoverable.

**To check this debavior**:

I suggest you could create a new empty project and then install these nuget packages one by one to check which package is the role. Or you can share these packages with us so that we can help you find it.

Comment: So I followed your suggested solution and created new project where I added dependencies one by one. It turns out that the package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK was responsible for creating this folder. Guess it's because .NET Core is supposed to be cross platform it needs all those DLL's to be able to run on unix systems. There is newer version of this package available and when I install it, it creates yet another folder called runtimes with unix and win subfolders