# NuGet: Prevent copy operation from NuGet subdirectory flat to OutputPath

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have created a NuGet package that contains Native Libraries in two subfolders (amd64 and x86). The NativeLibraries are supposed to be copied into subfolders of the OutputPath, which works. I used the following stackoverflow entry as a guide for creating the package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316946/4496150

The NuGet package folder structure looks like this:

- build

  - amd64

    - DLL1.dll
    - DLL2.dll
  - x86

    - DLL1.dll
    - DLL2.dll
  - packagename.targets

My targets file looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.dll" />
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, additionally the files are copied flat into the Outputpath during the build step (msbuild.exe, VS 2019). Since the files in the amd64 and x86 folders are named the same, they overwrite each other.

The crucial build output looks like this:

```
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\amd64\DLL1.dll" to "C:\Bin\amd64\DLL1.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\amd64\DLL2.dll" to "C:\Bin\amd64\DLL2.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\x86\DLL1.dll" to "C:\Bin\x86\DLL1.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\x86\DLL2.dll" to "C:\Bin\x86\DLL2.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\amd64\DLL1.dll" to "C:\Bin\DLL1.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\amd64\DLL2.dll" to "C:\Bin\DLL2.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\x86\DLL1.dll" to "C:\Bin\DLL1.dll".
Copying file from "C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME\1.2.3\build\x86\DLL2.dll" to "C:\Bin\DLL2.dll".
```

How can I prevent the NativeLibraries from being additionally copied flat to the Output folder?

Comment: Did you use a net core lib project or a non-sdk net framework proejct? And is your issue why the DLL1.dlls and DLL2.dlls are copied again into the root output folder?

Comment: Does it help when you set `<Private>False</Private>` on the `None` item? `None` and `Content` are also considered for assembly resolution and may be considered as local referenced assemblies

Comment: Hi MisterGray, any update about this issue? Please let us know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi @SaraLiu-MSFT Sorry for the delay, I didn't have access to my work computer to test it again. Please see my comment on your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created such nuget package with your guide and did not get the same behavior as you shown.

This is my nupkg:

[image]

[image]

Not sure whether there is an old cache under your the global cache.

Please try these:

assume that you used a non-sdk project net framework project.

**1)** first uninstall the nuget package under your project

**2)** [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under  `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\PACKAGENAME`

**Also**, delete `<solution_folder>\packages\PACKAGENAME.1.2.3` folder

**3)** reinstall the new version of the nuget package again.

Also, check whether your `packagename.targets` file has other node to affect that.

Comment: I can confirm that it works as I initially tried and as you described.
However, I still have problems when I add another NuGet package that contains Native Libraries without subfolders. I'll create another question for that though.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67198075/4496150