# Nuget Build, when it PackageName.Targets and PackageName.props consumed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Given, a package file called example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>example</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <title>$title$</title>
        <authors>$author$</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>$description$</description>
        <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="example.targets" target="build" />
        <file src="example.props" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

When is example.targets and example.props consumed?

Originally I thought it was only during the build process for the project that is using the Nuget package.

But it seems to use props files on installation?

I'm using old-style packages.config in my consuming projects.

Anyone point me to details on this or advise.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) said,

> .props is added at the top of the project file; .targets is added at
> the bottom.

`example.props` will be read first  when you install the nuget package into your project.

**Therefore**, properties will be available at the start of the build process.

It is usually used to define new global properties, or several new items
which can include some files into your project. **Properties** and **items** will be executed at this moment.

`example.targets` will be read when you build the project with the installed nuget package.

**Nuget** will import `.props` file very early in `Microsoft.Common.props`.

**And** the principle is actually the same as described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order).

**In more detail**, when you install a nuget package in the project, **nuget** will read the `csproj` file(add the reference node into `csproj` file).

**Because** when a nuget is installed, it will read a part of the `csproj` file, and only the content of the header part will be read, such as `Microsoft.Common.props` file, and the `.props` file is imported before it. So when you install the nuget package, the `.props` file will be read in its entirety, so any xml node of its content will be read and executed first.

**Therefore**, it will work when you install the nuget package.

**However**, `.targets` will be imported at the bottom of the `csproj` file. So when the nuget package is installed, it cannot reach there and the file cannot be read at all, so the file will only be read when the project is built.

**In fact**, `.props` file is read twice. One time is when nuget was installed, and another time is when you are building the project, but `.targets` can only be read when building the project.

**Update 1**

**Note**:

**For the target of MSBuild**, it is special. Some tasks like [copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2019) are written under a **target**. But if you execute a target with .props or .targets, you should execute the build process. So if you want to the target to be executed under installation process of nuget package, it obviously doesn't work. And you should execute build process to execute it. And when you install the nuget package, it will not execute the build process.

**So as I said before**, `.props` and `.targets` are the same when you use a target. When **MSBuild** reads the `.props` or `.targets` and enter the target, since the condition is like `BeforeTargets="Build"`, **however**, it is under installation process rather than build process so far. And `BeforeTargets="Build"` needs build process. So it will skip it.

`This happens 'once'` means msbuild reads the file first under the nuget installation process. It will get the properties or items which can include some files into your main project. **But** target depends on the build process, so **MSBuild** will skip it under the nuget installation process(which not execute the build yet).

Comment: Just for clarification, in the document, it just suggests that it adds the props file to the project. So what do you mean when you say "Will work when you install"?  Many thanks.

Comment: `.props` file is imported before `Microsoft.Common.props` while `.targets` is imported at the bottom of the csproj file. When you install a nuget package(it will read part of the csproj file and add reference node into `csproj`). So  only the top is read by the nuget package. However, `.props` file is imported before the header `Microsoft.Common.props`, so it will be read first when you install the nuget package.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more detailed info. You can check it. Hope it could help you understand it better:)

Comment: @PerryQain-MSFT - Thank you for the detailed answer,  although I am still stuck on your definition of 'Will work when you install"    Does this mean if you put any tasks in your Props file the will run during the Nuget install process?   Is there any benefits from props file being available during the install process, or is this just a side-effect of how it updates the csproj file?   My limited understanding is that it just renders any properties defined early on the build process so they can be consumed by targets later in the build process?

Comment: `.props` file are used for defining new properties or items(more likely to global variables) so that they can be got during the whole process while `.targets` file are used for overwriting known properties and operations. If you just define some properties or items to include some files, using `.props` file will import them without build process. If you use tasks with target, its running order depends on the target it depends on rather than the specificity of this file.

Comment: For an example, if you have a target that depends on Build like `<Target Name="test" BeforeTargets="Build"></Target>`, it depends on the build process. And it is not related with the particularity of the `.props` and `.targets` files .And as far as I know, if you use targets, you must execute the build process if you want to run them.

Comment: And the dependent targets are the content of the build process, so when you use the target, you must start the build process, and it has nothing to do with the `.props` and `.targets` files. For other contents of msbuild except target like properties or items, you can use the particularity of the `.props` and `.targets` files.

Comment: To be more specific, when using properties or items, you can use the particularity of the `.props` and `.targets` files as you want. And if you use targets, it is the same with `.props` and `.targets` files. And it depends on the build button.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant, any update about this issue? If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.  For context, I have extended my build process with '.Prop' and '.Target' files successfully - my sticking point is understanding when you say - "Therefore, it will work when you install the NuGet package".  The statement implies you can use the props file for 'something' during the NuGet install process.    For example, I have targets file currently that copies certain files to my build output process.

Comment: This happens 'once' when built and not on any subsequent builds.  Is it possible to move this to Nuget install/update/restore steps?  Hence trying to understand your original statement.

Comment: copy task are written under a target. But if you execute a target with `.props` or `.targets`, you should execute the build process. So if you want to the target to be executed under installation process of nuget package, it obviously doesn't work. And you should execute build process to execute it. And when you install the nuget package, it will not execute the build process.

Comment: So as I said before, `.props` and `.targets` are the same when you use a target. When msbuild reads the `.props` or `.targets` and enter the target, since the condition is like `BeforeTargets="Build"`, however, it is under installation process rather than build process. And `BeforeTargets="Build"` needs build process. So it will skip it.

Comment: That makes sense,  but can you clarify if you can do anything with the props file,  or should the sentence - "Therefore, it will work when you install the NuGet package."  actually be "Therefore, properties will be available at the start of the build process."

Comment: `This happens 'once'` means msbuild reads the file first under the nuget installation process. It will get the `properties` or `items` which can include some files into your main project. But target depends on the build process so msbuild will skip it under the nuget installation process(which not execute the build yet).

Comment: And if you want to copy these files  during nuget installation, you should not use the target. And you can [use powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759795/nuget-copy-and-add-files-to-solution-level/20914484). See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory).

Comment: I think we stretching the limits of StackOverflow comments - is there discord?  -The power shell script is not run when NuGet is restored outside of visual studio from my understanding.   Can  I use Props to add other elements to my project file then, this is the bit I'm confused on.  Sorry for the back and forth!

Comment: :) ha-ha. It doesn't matter:)  using powershell is a suggestion and sorry for that I am not familiar with that. For `.props` file, If you add some global properties or items, it is okay and you can use these under `.props` file during nuget installation. Also, the target also can be written there and it is just that you need to click build to execute that. That is enough and might not be complex. I have updated my answer and you can check it:)