# How can I create a solution level NuGet package for an entire project?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I have created a NuGet gallery in my company.
I want to create and publish a solution level NuGet package.
Everyone who will install the package will not get a dll but an entire project added to his/her visual studio solution.
Just like adding an existing project, the user will get a project with source code classes and everything is ready to use.
Just build it and use  it.

I know it's possible, but couldn't find any documentation.

Anyone?

Comment: I would go with a multi-project template VSIX instead, however, you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6460854/38368

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to add any files (not only .dll) and even directory structures to a NuGet package, so in theory you could store all files belonging to a project in a package and publish that. However, it is only possible to install NuGet packages **into an existing project**, meaning that you won't be able to add the packaged files as new project to any solution. In addition, the contained files will be put to the solution's `packages` folder, not to a solution or project folder.

As an alternative, consider creating a *Template project* instead of a NuGet package, as explained in [How to: Create Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) and my blog post [Creating template projects](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=736). This will result in a .vsix file that any developer can install as Visual Studio Add-In, the templated project will then appear in Visual Studio's *File -> New -> Project... dialog* as new project type and can be added to any solution.

Similar to your NuGet gallery, it is also possible to create a private Visual Studio Gallery to share such Add-Ins within, for example, a company, as explained in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx).

Comment: There are solutions for adding files to the solution itself that involve adding scripts to the package. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6460854/38368