# Add files in solution level by nuget

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I want to add items (not projects) to a solution via a NuGet, but I have created a Nuspec file with the following files elements:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\A.txt" target="content" />
</files>
```

But the file `A.txt` is added to the project not solution. So I want to know is  there any way to add the file to solution level not the project level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I want to know is there any way to add the file to solution level not the project level?

I am afraid there is no such direct way to do that. Because NuGet team [deprecated solution level package](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522)s in NuGet 3.0.

So, at this moment, the nuget is package manager for project level, we could not add the file to solution level directly .

However, you can do this by `install.ps1` file. Matt provided the PowerShell script in following thread, you can refer to:

[Adding solution-level items in a NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460854/adding-solution-level-items-in-a-nuget-package)

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, it seems I need to use the install.ps1, hope that can helps.